# Ionic_ Unable connect data from app.js to index.html

Tags: android, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a mobile app using Ionic but, I am having a hard time connecting index.html to get the data. I am pretty new at this, can somebody please help me figure it out ?

Basically, in the app I want to show a list of restaurants. Using Cards Images, I would like to show an image, a logo, the name of the restaurant and a description.

Here is my code for index.html

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang ="en" data-ng-app="restaurantList">
              <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Food</title>

                  <!--Ionic Libraries-->
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" type="text/css" />
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

                  <!--My App-->
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
              </head>
              <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">

               <div class="bar bar-header bar-light">
                  <h1 class="title">Food</h1>
                </div>

              <ion-content>
                  <div ng-repeat= "item in items" class="list card">
                    <div class="item item-image">
                      <img ng-src="{{ item.cover }}"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item item-avatar">
                      <img ng-src="{{ item.logo }}">
                      <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
                      <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </ion-content>  


              </body>
            </html>
```

Here is my code for app.js

```
            angular.Module('restaurantList', ['ionic'])

            .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
                $scope.items = [
                    { 
                        id: 1, 
                        cover: 'img/destination/hankburger/cover.jpg', 
                        logo: 'img/destination/hankburger/logo.png', 
                        name: 'Hank Burger',
                        description: 'Uhmmm... des Hankburgers'
                    },
                    { 
                        id: 2, 
                        cover: 'img/destination/elmida/cover.jpg', 
                        logo: 'img/destination/hankburger/logo.jpeg', 
                        name: 'El Mida',
                        description: 'Salon de thé traiteur oriental'
                    }
                    ];
            });
```

I am also attaching a screen-shot of my file structure. Can you please help me figure-out what is wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVJe5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Defining your angular `module` should be lowercase

```
angular.module('restaurantList', ['ionic'])
//      ^should be lowercase
```

Comment: hey man, that actually just solved the issue. i have been debugging for days... :) thanks